# Problem with GetLastError API on windows 7

Tags: winapi, windows-7, getlasterror

I have one application that interacts with the server. If the server is down then then I will get `ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT` I am using `getLastError()` API to get this error code, I am handling this error code to display proper error messages to the users. This program works fine in Windows 2003. When i tried with Windows7 i am not getting any error, `getLastError()` API returns 0 every time even if error is occurred. I am using C++ as of programming language is concerned.

Thanks In advance

Santhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have observed different behavior of GetLastError API in Windows 2003 and in Windows 7. 
Below are my observation details

**In windows 2003:**

Example Code:

`WinHttpOpen ()` – Completes successfully

`Winhttpconnect()` – This API is failed due to some reasons, say error code 12029

`GetLastErrorCode()` – Returns error code 12029 as expected

`WinHttpCloseHandle(hOpen)`; - Closing handle for HttpOpen, completes successfilly

`GetLastErrorCode()` – Returns error code 12029

**In Windows 7**

Example Code:

`WinHttpOpen ()` – Completes successfully

`Winhttpconnect()` – This API is failed due to some reasons, say error code 12029

`GetLastErrorCode()` – Returns error code 12029 as expected

`WinHttpCloseHandle(hOpen);` - Closing handle for HttpOpen, completes successfully

`GetLastErrorCode()` – Returns error code 0 // *see the difference with Windows 2003 example, on windows 2003 this API returns last error which is 1209*

Answer (score 0):

If you make any Windows API calls between the failure and the time you call GetLastError(), the error code can get reset to 0 when that API call succeeds.

You need to call GetLastError() immediately after the failure, and save that value rather than trying to wait and call GetLastError() later.

Answer (score 0):

Answer From Microsoft on this behaviuor

```
The rules for GetLastError are:

•   If the WinHttp API returns error (for example WinHttpIsHostInProxyBypassList, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861268(VS.85).aspx) this is the error and GetLastError should *NOT* be called.
o   If GetLastError() is called, regardless of the success or failure of the API, the returned value is unpredictable and may change between Windows versions, Service Packs, or even between runs.
•   If the WinHttp API returns BOOL (for example WinHttpSetTimeouts, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384116(VS.85).aspx), it indicates failure by returning FALSE. If the caller is interested in the detailed error, (s)he should call GetLastError(). Note that GetLastError should be called *if and only if* the API failed.
o   If GetLastError() is called when the API succeded (returned anything but FALSE), the returned value is unpredictable and may change between Windows versions, Service Packs, or even between runs. 
•   If the WinHttp API returns HINTERNET (pseudo handle) the rules are exactly the same, except failure is indicated by returning NULL. 
o   If GetLastError() is called when the API succeded (returned anything but NULL), the returned value is unpredictable and may change between Windows versions, Service Packs, or even between runs.
```